# Prove $\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\left(1-x^2-y^2\right)^{\left(n/2\right)-1} {\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y = 2\pi/n$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

As the title says, I want to show that
\begin{align}
&\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\left(1 - x^{2} - y^{2}\right)^{\left(n/2\right) - 1}\,
{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y = 2\pi/n
\\&\left(~\mbox{this came up in finding a recursion for the volume of}\
n\mbox{-dimensional spheres}~\right)
\end{align}
I feel like a substition might work here. Does anyone have a hint for me ?.

Comment: I could show it using polar coordinates and then solving $\int_{0}^{1}(\sqrt{1-r^2})^{n-2}rdr$

Comment: The accepted answer solves the case when the domain of integration is the unit *disk* but the question asks about the *square* $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$. By the way, what is the meaning of the (possibly noninteger) power of $1-x^2-y^2$ in the integral when $x^2+y^2\gt1$ (a case which happens, when in the square)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using polar coordinates, we get $\int_{0}^{1}(\sqrt{1-r^2})^{n-2}rdr=\dfrac{1}{n}$. Substituting back gives the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When you are integrating with respect to $x,$ $y$ is a constant, so you just need to integrate $\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}.$ Can you?

Comment: what is $a^2$ here?

Comment: Well, if $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} = \sqrt{a^2 - x^2},$ what is $a?$

Comment: Oh, then $a^2=1-y^2$. I'm not sure how to integrate here though, since we have that power of $n-2$ in there.

Comment: Well, if $n$ is even, it should be ok. Can you do it then?